# How to extend the timeout for browser.debug?

Tags: javascript, cucumber, timeout, webdriver-io

When I have a Cucumber step definition in JavaScript using WebdriverIO and call:

```
browser.debug();
```

...it times out in ten seconds, which is never long enough. Several docs and blog posts advise something like [this answer's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47176108/3001761) *"Note: The default timeout for the .debug() command is short. Make sure you increase it."* But none spell out exactly how to do that.

I've tried things like:

```
browser.debug({wait: 120000});
```

...and this, in `wdio.conf.js`:

```
exports.config = merge(configs, {
  waitforTimeout: 120000,
  connectionRetryTimeout: 90000,
  framework: 'cucumber',
  cucumberOpts: {
    timeout: 60000,
```

Neither of these (and similar attempts) have extended the debug timeout.

How can I extend the `browser.debug` timeout in a Cucumber step definition?

Comment: [The docs](https://webdriver.io/docs/api/browser/debug/) suggest you increase the timeout _of the test framework_, not the command (which likely doesn't have its own timeout, that wouldn't make sense). https://webdriver.io/docs/timeouts/#framework-related-timeouts suggests that should work for Cucumber, what output do you get?

Comment: Thanks, @jonrsharpe. I have the framework timeout at 60 seconds (see `cucumberOpts.timeout`, above), as your link suggests. But `debug` still times out in 10 seconds. The only output I'm seeing is ` function timed out, ensure the promise resolves within 10000 milliseconds`

Comment: ...but today, it is working. :head_scratch: `cucumberOpts.timeout` works as advertised. Guess I had some other wires crossed yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

Control the timeout (in milliseconds) in `cucumberOpts`. For example, in `wdio.conf.js`:

```
exports.config = merge(configs, {
  cucumberOpts: {
    timeout: 60000,
  }
}
```